# OpenThread certification on Border Router

Tags: openthread

On the *Thread Test Harness Software Installation* and *Quick Start Guide* there is no mention regarding how to certificate a **Border Router**.

Always it is talking about the **DUT**, but it doesn't mention if the **DUT** is an end device, or a **Border Router**. We are not `Contributor`, or `Sponsor` in the *Thread Group*, so we don't have access to *Thread Test Harness Software*.

On [OpenThread](https://openthread.io/certification/prerequisites) documentation:

> For example, to build the CC2538 platform with DHCPv6 for use as a DUT in certification tests:
>
> ```
> make -f example/Makefile-cc2538 BORDER_ROUTER=1 COMMISSIONER=1 DHCP6_CLIENT=1 JOINER=1
> ```

When OpenThread project claim that is [Thread Certified on CC2538 device as Border Router or Full End Device](https://openthread.io/certification/11A001_2017_02_09.pdf), what does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread devices may support a varying set of capabilities, including:

- Sleepy End Device
- Minimal End Device
- Full Thread Device
- Full End Device
- On-Mesh Commissioner
- Border Router

The Thread Certification Test specification includes a set of tests for each of the capabilities above.  The set of tests applied to a DUT are selected based on the device's stated capabilities.

OpenThread has achieved certification on all of the capabilities above (and as listed on the certificate you linked).